# How do I re-evaluate a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a routine that runs one of 2 pieces of code depending on the value of a named range (LTV).

The issue is that at the time of the evaluation of the named range (LTV) is made it does not meet the criteria to trigger the PushTo95Button routine but after the code in the "else" is executed the criteria is now met to call the first routine (PushTo95Button). I have to run the macro twice to get the desired result.

How I can evaluate the named range (LTV) after the first pass?

```
Sub PushTo105Button()
Range("D22").Value = 0
If Range("PropertyType").Value = "Condo" And Range("LTV").Value > 0.95 Then
   Call PushTo95Button
Else
   Range("LoanAmount").Value = Worksheets("Closing Costs").Range("I3")
End If
Call Calc_MI
End Sub
```

Comment: A bit confused - why don't you flip the logic around? Check if the criteria is not met, if so make the required change, otherwise proceed to `PushTo95Button`. In other words, I'm not sure why `PushTo95Button` is within the `If`.

Comment: Wow, you pointed out the most obvious solution and I was so caught up in thinking it another way. I actually just ran this code first "Range("LoanAmount").Value = Worksheets("Closing Costs").Range("I3")" that calculates the true LTV and then do the evaluation and it worked like a charm. I had my logic all screwed up

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to BigBen I rethought the logic and rearranged the code to where the criteria is checked first:

```
Sub PushTo105Button()
Range("D22").Value = 0
Range("LoanAmount").Value = Worksheets("Closing Costs").Range("I3")
Range("LoanAmount").Value = Worksheets("Closing Costs").Range("I3")
Call Calc_MI
End Sub
```